# Short story from the 80s - Character has to read instead of having brain programed

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I had a collection of Science-Fiction short stories back in the 80s. There was one story set in the future where everyone went through a programming process that would "teach" them how to perform the necessary skills for specific careers. The main character's brain is not programmable and is sent to a home with others with the same problem. Once there, the character decides to learn the skills required by reading.

The collection had a version of Enemy Mine.

I would love to find that story and use it in class.

Comment: Sounds like Asimov's ["Profession"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55700), a [frequently identified](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstory-identification%5D+is%3Aanswer+asimov+profession) story. It has a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profession_(short_story)).

Comment: You might have read in in [this](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?178085) 1985 anthology.

Comment: @user14111 - Dupe. Hammertime! Can't touch this.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is it. Thank you!